# Do MAUI apps run on Linux?

Tags: linux, maui-blazor

is it possible to run a .NET MAUI app natively on Linux? I need to run a Blazor WebApp (server side) on a Linux machine and I'd like to avoid running it in a browser. I need the app to be in fullscreen, in the foreground with no close button or similar. I don't need to debug the app on the machine. Is this possible?

Comment: Not natively, no.  There is a fork you might try, but there's so many better alternatives.  https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/maui-linux

Comment: Thanks. Would you care to elaborate on those better options? Cause right now as I see it, it's either MAUI or a browser.

Comment: Pick a Linux-supported UI framework.  For the C# ecosystem, I'd personally start with Avalonia or GTK with C# bindings.  I'd also consider running it in a VM with native windowing support which could be pretty seamless.

Comment: I see. This was my bad for not explaining the problem parameters. The app is already developed. A team of programmers labored on it for months. My question was about choosing an environment/strategy to run that specific app, not choosing a UI technology to run specifically on Linux.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're out of luck unfortunately.  Browser or VM then, I guess.

Comment: According to the official statement, the Linux version of Maui Blazor Hybrid is not yet officially supported, but they intentionally rely on .NET MAUI for the cross-platform host. You follow this link: [Support Blazor Hybrid on Linux/Ubuntu](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11738).